# Can I get the images for printers in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, printers

If I open up "Devices and Printers" on my machine (Windows 7), I see something like this for the printers:

[image: Printers with Images]

Is there a way to get these images from the OS in my WPF application?  I would like to list printers much like this, but right now I only have the text for the printers (not the images).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [`SetupDiLoadDeviceIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552057%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You'll have to read up on MSDN and play with p-Invoke a bit to get this working from the managed side...

The info comes from registry, but you shouldn't look for it yourself. See [Providing Vendor Icons for the Shell and AutoPlay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549789%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).